# Override of prototype.toString() is not working in OOP function

Tags: javascript, overriding, prototype, tostring

I am trying to override .toString() in a JavaScript object I am creating. However, it does not seem to be honored.

This is the piece of code in question:

```js
const FormBuilderObject = function() {
  var categories = [];
  var questions = [];

  return {
    initCategory: function() {
      return new CATEGORY();
    },
    initQuestion: function() {
      return new QUESTION();
    },
    getQuestions: function() {
      return questions;
    },
    getCategories: function() {
      return categories;
    },
    addCategory: function(category) {
      categories.push(category);
    },
    addQuestion: function(question) {
      questions.push(question);
    }
  }
};

FormBuilderObject.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "echo base";
}

var f = new FormBuilderObject();

alert(f);
```

This yields, "[object Object]", which is incorrect.

However, doing it this way - works:

```js
    var Foof = function() {}

    Foof.prototype.toString = function() {
      return "echo base";
    }

    var F = new Foof();

    alert(F);
```

This one returns "echo base"

I am not quite sure why the first is not working but the second is. The syntax is about the same?

Is there something else that I am doing that I am unaware of?

Comment: I suspect it is something to do with the return { } in the first function. However, I am not sure what else to do in order to expose certain functions. I was hoping the .toString() would give me the option to render the return object explicitly when called or invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is

```
console.log(f instanceof FormBuilderObject) //false
```

When you use `new` keyword it automatically return an object `this` which is instanceof that constructor. But here you are not returning that instance but instead returning your own object which is not instance of `FormBuilderObject`

> The new keyword does the following things
>   
>     4. Returns `this` if the function doesn't return its own object.

**So if you `return` something inside constructor the the variable will not be instanceof the constructor**

You should add method to `this` like below

```js
const FormBuilderObject = function() {
  var categories = [];
  var questions = [];
  this.initCategory = function() {
    return new CATEGORY();
  }
  this.initQuestion = function() {
     return new QUESTION();
  }
  this.getQuestions = function() {
     return questions;
  }
  this.getCategories = function() {
      return categories;
  }
  this.addCategory = function(category) {
      categories.push(category);
  }
  this.addQuestion = function(question) {
      questions.push(question);
  }

};

FormBuilderObject.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "echo base";
}

var f = new FormBuilderObject();

alert(f);
```

Comment: What would be the best way to make this object easily serializable?

Answer (score 1):

JS lets constructors override the `new` object by returning an alternate object. Therefore, the `new FormBuilderObject();` is just giving the returned plain object that inherits from `Object.prototype`, and not one that inherits from `FormBuilderObject`.

As far as what to do, you could add a `toString` method to the object being returned, though generally you'd just put the `categories` and `questions` arrays directly on the `new` object, but name them with a leading underscore to indicate that they're not to be directly accessed.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that the constructors were able to override the new object! That is totally new to me!

Comment: Will it be protected with a leading underscore?

Comment: @BarryChapman: Yep, it's weird. Only objects work like this, not primitives.

Comment: No, it's just a convention to use the underscore that way.

Comment: Interesting. So what would be the best way to structure the 'new' object?

Comment: All depends on how important it is for you to protect those arrays. You can keep your current structure, but instead of returning an object literal, add all those methods to `this` in the constructor.

Comment: ...`this.initCategory = function() {
      return new CATEGORY();
    },` ...and so on... though I'd only do it for the methods that actually need to access the protected arrays.

Comment: It isn't that important. I just need to be able to serialize this whole mess when it is done

Comment: Then I'd put the arrays as properties on the object, and keep the methods on the prototype. Should make it easier to serialize since you can keep limit the serialization to only the "own" properties instead of the inherited ones.